# Changing a week number to a month number-teradata

Tags: teradata

I am trying to change a week number to a month number in teradata. I have an origial column that  i broke up which looked like, 201642 (YYYY/WW). I broke out just the week from there. That column is labeled fiscal_week. But I need to do some analysis against data that is in a monthly format. how do i go about this? I am new to teradata so I need the whole statement worked out including the select, from, and where (if any) statements.

Comment: ISO week or not? When does a week start, Sunday or Monday? What's the week number around new year? To which month a week should be mapped?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in `sys_calendar.calendar` table for this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT year_of_calendar * 100 + month_of_year FROM sys_calendar.calendar WHERE year_of_calendar * 100 + week_of_year = 201642
```

Which will spit out `201610`